# how to set the flyway community version to pro version

Tags: flyway

Is there any proper documentation available for flyway for step by step process. For instance how to set the licence-key to pro version from the community version?How to set the environment variable to assign the value FLYWAY_EDITION TO PRO

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the configuration file setting for edition.  I've been using the commandline switch "-pro" or "-enterprise".

I've been referencing the Key with this variable in the conf files..."flyway.licenseKey=FL01<512 bit key>"

If you have the variable you *have* to use the commandline switch, and if you use the commandline switch, you have to have the variable, either in the .conf or passed on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows: either use the environment variables dialog to create a FLYWAY_EDITION variable and set its value, or use Powershell:

`set-item -path env:FLYWAY_EDITION -value 'pro'`

In Linux:

`export FLYWAY_EDITION=pro`

Note that the valid values are `community`, `pro` and `enterprise` and are case-sensitive. Setting any of the command-line flags will override the environment.